# getStringExtra giving java.lang.NullPointerException error

Tags: android

i am sending the values to pag2.java as follows

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), page2.class);
        intent.putExtra("pos", list1);
        intent.putExtra("back1", "back");
        startActivity(myIntent);
```

And recieving in page2 as

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        pos = intent.getStringExtra("pos");
```

I am getting the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.namrathasrinivas.karnatakatemples, PID: 4410
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.namrathasrinivas.karnatakatemples/com.example.namrathasrinivas.karnatakatemples.page2}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
        at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
        at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:139)
        at com.example.namrathasrinivas.karnatakatemples.page2.onCreate(page2.java:41)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
```

Comment: why is this line of code in your intent                                   intent.putExtra("back1", "back".toString());       I think It should be  intent.putExtra("back1", "back");

Comment: Have you declared String pos;

Comment: please post the logcat error, so we can know more details of the error. :)

Comment: What is this "back".toString()

Comment: make sure  list1 is not null

Comment: why are you using getApplicationContext use context

Comment: post more code.. maybe all class

Comment: you are printing a null value in your log

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Next time, google your error, it will save everyone some time, including yourself.

Comment: my line no 41 is Log.d("val",pos);

Comment: then definitely pos is null

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String str =  bundle.getString("pos");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try this way because you might have error in transferring the data between activities (it has something to do with savedInstanceState)

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) String pos = extras.getString("pos");
```

If this still does not work ok, then you might have problems with your manifest. Have you declared your receiving activity in the proper way?